# How to make customize input border without removing outline focus on Firefox/IE

Tags: css, firefox, focus, accessibility, outline

**Important**: I do not want to customize/remove focus styles for accessibility (a11y) purpose. It is basically [impossible to mimic all the different focus styles of browsers/operating systems](https://allyjs.io/tests/focus-outline-styles/#style=focus&key=text,radio,checkbox,textarea,button,link,div&browser=firefox,chrome,safari,ie11)

Customizing the look and feel of an input/textarea removes the outline style when the element is focused. Also it adds weird border etc.

What is the reason behind this behavior, in my opinion it destroys accessibility? How not to override focus styles while modifying simple CSS properties like background, borders color etc?

I tested on Firefox Mac and IE 11 (Chrome works fine), maybe other browser acts the same.
Here is a Codepen to try it in the browser: https://codepen.io/lbineau/pen/dLgwoo

```html
<label for="customized-input">Customized input</label>
<input id="customized-input" type="text" />

<label for="native-input">Native input</label>
<input id="native-input" type="text" />
```

**Expected result**: the default outline should be displayed even if the input border is customized.

**Actual result**: outline does not appear when the input is focused.

Comment: Question, why no do a css reset so it will look the same for all browsers? Starting up with Normalize.css for example would be a great way to start things off. You could go further by doing a reboot. If your planning to use bootstrap in the future I recommand bootstrap boot. More information about reset and reboot you can find here: https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not actually looking to normalize the behavior of the browser but the opposite, a way not to break the browser behavior.
For the record I use normalize.css for years. I did not add it on codepen sample on purpose to have the "raw" of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason behind this.

But you can override it with the following code:

```
#customized-input:-moz-focusring {
  outline: Highlight solid 1px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm more looking for an explanation rather than a solution. 
Doing what you suggest, assumes all mozilla firefox are using this specific outline. I'm pretty sure that if you check on windows/mac os/linux/android/ios firefox they don't have the kind of outline (some or solid/dotted/blured etc).

Answer (score 0):

If the element css which you want to change is sibling, you can use like this,

```
        <label class="label-class" for="customized-input">Customized input</label>
        <input id="customized-input" type="text" />

        
  .customized-input:focus ~.label-class {
        &::before {
            border:1px solid red;
            height:40px;
            width: 40px;
       
  }
}
```